# Draw line on touch event mono for android

Tags: android, xamarin.android, line, draw

I tried creating two circles ondraw in a activity. But what I really want to accomplish is to draw a line on touch move. The user will be able to use his/her finger to draw a line depending on the finger's movement. Here's how I dot my drawing.

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        currentLevel = Intent.GetIntExtra("gameLevel", 0);
        playerScore = Intent.GetIntExtra("score", 0);
        SetContentView(new SampleView(this));


        // Create your application here
    }

    private class SampleView : View
    {
        private Paint mPaint;

        public SampleView(Context context)
            : base(context)
        {
            Focusable = true;

            mPaint = new Paint();
            mPaint.AntiAlias = true;
        }

        protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
        {
            canvas.DrawColor(Color.White);

            canvas.Translate(10, 10);

            canvas.SaveLayerAlpha(0, 0, 200, 200, 0x88, SaveFlags.All);

            mPaint.Color = Color.Red;
            canvas.DrawCircle(75, 75, 75, mPaint);
            mPaint.Color = Color.Blue;
            canvas.DrawCircle(125, 125, 75, mPaint);

            canvas.Restore();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a project which shows how to draw on a Canvas with your finger:

https://github.com/Cheesebaron/MonoDroid.CaptureSignature

You are probably interested in the `CaptureSignatureView` which holds all the logic for the drawing on the canvas.

Comment: Is there any Example Project, since this link is dead?
I am looking for Drawing on Images in Xamarin.Android

Comment: Latest code here: https://github.com/Cheesebaron/CaptureSignature/ Otherwise there is also the Xamarin University AND240 class which goes through this.

Answer (score -1):

Try out the below code:

> ```
> public class FingerDrawView extends View
>    {
> private Paint m_paint;
> private static Bitmap m_bitmap;
> private Canvas m_canvas;
> private Path m_path;
> private Paint m_bitmapPaint;
> private DisplayMetrics m_metrics;
> private int m_color = 0xFFFF0000;
> static boolean m_pathDrawn = false;
> private float m_X, m_Y;
> private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;
>
> public FingerDrawView(Context p_c)
> {
>     super(p_c);
>     m_paint = new Paint();
>     m_paint.setAntiAlias(true);
>     m_paint.setDither(true);
>     m_paint.setColor(m_color);
>     new ColorPickerDialog(p_c, new OnColorChangedListener()
>     {
>         public void colorChanged(int p_color)
>         {
>             m_paint.setColor(p_color);
>             m_color = p_color;
>         }
>     }, 0xFFFF0000).show();
>     m_paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
>     m_paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
>     m_paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
>     m_paint.setStrokeWidth(12);
>     m_metrics = p_c.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
>     m_bitmap =
>             Bitmap.createBitmap(m_metrics.widthPixels, m_metrics.heightPixels,
>                     Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
>     m_canvas = new Canvas(m_bitmap);
>     m_path = new Path();
>     m_bitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
> }
>
> public void onerase()
> {
>     m_canvas = null;
> }
>
> @Override
> protected void onSizeChanged(int p_w, int p_h, int p_oldw, int p_oldh)
> {
>     super.onSizeChanged(p_w, p_h, p_oldw, p_oldh);
> }
>
> @Override
> protected void onDraw(Canvas p_canvas)
> {
>     p_canvas.drawColor(0x00000000);
>     p_canvas.drawBitmap(m_bitmap, 0, 0, m_bitmapPaint);
>     p_canvas.drawPath(m_path, m_paint);
> }
>
> private void touch_start(float p_x, float p_y)
> {
>     m_path.reset();
>     m_path.moveTo(p_x, p_y);
>     m_X = p_x;
>     m_Y = p_y;
> }
>
> private void touch_move(float p_x, float p_y)
> {
>     float m_dx = Math.abs(p_x - m_X);
>     float m_dy = Math.abs(p_y - m_Y);
>     if (m_dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || m_dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE)
>     {
>         m_path.quadTo(m_X, m_Y, (p_x + m_X) / 2, (p_y + m_Y) / 2);
>         m_X = p_x;
>         m_Y = p_y;
>         m_pathDrawn = true;
>     }
> }
>
> private void touch_up()
> {
>     m_path.lineTo(m_X, m_Y);
>     // commit the path to our offscreen
>     m_canvas.drawPath(m_path, m_paint);
>     // kill this so we don't double draw
>     m_path.reset();
> }
> @Override
> public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent p_event)
> {
>     float m_x = p_event.getX();
>     float m_y = p_event.getY();
>     switch (p_event.getAction())
>         {
>             case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
>                 touch_start(m_x, m_y);
>                 invalidate();
>                 break;
>             case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
>                 touch_move(m_x, m_y);
>                 invalidate();
>                 break;
>             case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
>                 touch_up();
>                 invalidate();
>                 break;
>         }
>     return true;
> }
>   }
> ```

Use the above class as below:

> ```
>     FingerDrawView   m_cv = new FingerDrawView(MainActivity.this);
>   setContentView(m_cv);
> ```

I hope it will help you.

Thanks

Comment: What if I want to draw on an imageview as my canvas? I'm trying to create a tracing game where the player will have to connect the dots to form an image. Thanks!

Comment: And do you have a code for this using C#? I'm using mono for android.

Comment: Will try to convert it to C#

Comment: How about making an ImageView as my canvas? I want to draw there on touch event. Java code will do, I can translate it I think.